# How to install Magento security patch for Enterprise Edition (Commerce)?

Tags: magento-enterprise, patches, security, enterprise-1.14

How can I get Magento patches for Enterprise Edition (now *Magento Commerce*), I have followed:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#get-ee

but not getting the exact path. I want to install patch **SUPEE-10415**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login: https://account.magento.com/customer/account/login

Go to:

`Downloads > Magento Commerce 1.X > Support Patches and Security Patches > Security Patches - November 2017 > SUPEE-10415`

and select the appropriate version.

Your account has to have access to the Magento Commerce (Enterprise) editions to be able to access these resources for download.

*Note the Switch Accounts dropdown towards the top right if your Commerce resources are available through a shared account.

**EDIT**

You can also find all patches for CE & EE at - https://github.com/brentwpeterson/magento-patches